# Adding form functions dynamically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a hidden form element (as part of a large form) which needs to be created and added dynamically. A snippet of what I have so far is:

```
var value = '*****';
var inputHidden = $('<input>').attr('type', 'hidden')).addClass("warningOnly").val(value);
// conditionally disable new element here
$(elem).append(inputHidden);
```

This works as expected. What I also want to do is conditionally disable the hidden input before adding it to the form. What I have tried are variants of:

```
$(inputHidden).prop('disabled', true);
```

This does not disable the element and I need a way of doing this.

Comment: What benefit is there in disabling a hidden input? What are you trying to accomplish with hidden input?

Comment: check your `.attr('type', `hidden`))` -- you double-close the end parenthesis. Shouldn't matter, but its a thing.

Comment: a disabled hidden input won't be sent to the backend with the form submit. for example.

Comment: As I said, part of a larger form and the point is to stop the submit of the element if other conditions are met.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it by disabling the input via the attr, not via the prop? Something like this:

```
$('#test1').attr('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 3):

Works fine, or as a [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/r1qq8s3a/):

```js
$(function(){
  var value = '*****';
  var elem = $(".foo");
  var inputHidden = $('<input>')
        .attr('type', 'hidden')
        .addClass("warningOnly")
        .val(value);
  // conditionally disable new element here
  elem.append(inputHidden);

  inputHidden.prop("disabled", true);
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="foo">
Your hidden el will go here. Check the console to see that its disabled. 

</form>
```